# CTS is failing due to internet permission

Tags: android, cts

I am executing the Compatability Test Suite (CTS) but it is failing with the following errors:

```
android.permission2.cts.PermissionPolicyTest#testPlatformPermissionPolicyUnaltered fail: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Permission android.permission.INTERNET invalid enforced protection level flags expected:<4096> but was:<0>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:287)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:67)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:199)
    at android.permission2.cts.PermissionPolicyTest.testPlatformPermissionPolicyUnaltered(PermissionPolicyTest.java:114)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.runProtected(AndroidTestResult.java:77)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.run(AndroidTestResult.java:55)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.NonLeakyTestSuite$NonLeakyTest.run(NonLeakyTestSuite.java:63)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestSuite$2.run(AndroidTestSuite.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

    05-31 11:31:38
```

Comment: Have you made any modifications to AOSP around permissions? Are you using AOSP as downloaded directly, or a modified version?

Comment: AOSP as downloaded ..not modified